# to minimize the billing i need to add a field mask in the flutter code but when i add field mask the method not working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-places-api

i only want to call Basic Data form google autocomplete Api to minimize the billing i need to add a field mask, I only want to get the coordinates using the place id normally method is working but when trying to add the field mask the method is not working

Future setCustomMarker(String placeId) async {
final details = await GoogleMapsPlaces(
apiKey: 'Api key',
).getDetailsByPlaceId(placeId);

```
if (details.result.geometry != null) {
  final location = details.result.geometry!.location;
  double lat = location.lat;
  double lng = location.lng;
  LatLng destination = LatLng(lat, lng);
  endLocation = destination;

  // Generate custom marker icon
  BitmapDescriptor customIcon = await CustomMapMarker.getCustomMarkerIcon(
    Colors.green, // Fill color
    Colors.black, // Border color
    52.0, // Size of the marker
  );

  setState(() {
    isTextFieldVisible = false;
    _markers.clear();
    _markers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(placeId),
        position: destination,
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          snippet:  details.result.name,
          title:'Your destination ',
        ),
        icon: customIcon, // Set the custom icon here
      ),
    );
  });

  mapController.animateCamera(
    CameraUpdate.newLatLngZoom(destination, 14.5),
  );
}
```

}